# I am trying to make a clock app and I cant figure out the circle progress bar around it

Tags: python, pyqt5, progress-bar

I built the clock and the circle progress bar around it and I cant seem to make the circle progress bar start again and not go back the same way to the start.

The circle progress bar completes a circle every minute but instead of starting again the circle progress bar goes back the came way it came from

I also tried taking help from chatGPT but he also couldnt figure it out

```py
import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen, QPainterPath


class BackgroundWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BackgroundWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.background_color = QColor(30, 30, 30)  # Dark gray color
        self.progress_color = QColor(255, 255, 255)  # White color for progress

        self.progress = 0.0
        self.target_progress = 0.0
        self.animation_duration = 1000  # Animation duration in milliseconds
        self.animation_steps = 60  # Number of steps for animation
        self.direction = 1  # 1 for forward direction, -1 for reverse direction

        self.animation_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.animation_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_progress)

        self.progress_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.progress_timer.timeout.connect(self.update_target_progress)
        self.progress_timer.start(1000)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Set the background color
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), self.background_color)

        # Draw the progress arc
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        radius = min(width, height) * 0.4
        center_x = width // 2
        center_y = height // 2

        # Calculate the start and end angles based on progress
        start_angle = 90
        end_angle = start_angle - 360 * self.progress

        pen = QPen(self.progress_color)
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        # Create the progress path
        progress_path = QPainterPath()
        progress_path.arcMoveTo(
            center_x - radius, center_y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2, start_angle
        )
        progress_path.arcTo(
            center_x - radius,
            center_y - radius,
            radius * 2,
            radius * 2,
            start_angle,
            end_angle - start_angle,
        )

        # Draw the progress path
        painter.drawPath(progress_path)

    def update_target_progress(self):
        current_time = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        seconds = current_time.time().second()

        self.target_progress = seconds / 60.0

        # Start the animation timer if not already running
        if not self.animation_timer.isActive():
            self.animation_timer.start(self.animation_duration // self.animation_steps)

    def update_progress(self):
        progress_step = (
            self.direction
            * (self.target_progress - self.progress)
            / self.animation_steps
        )
        self.progress += progress_step

        if abs(self.progress - self.target_progress) <= abs(progress_step):
            self.progress = self.target_progress
            self.animation_timer.stop()

            # Reverse the direction if the progress reaches the end
            self.direction *= -1

        self.update()
        # Check if one circle is completed and reset progress smoothly
        if self.progress >= 1.0:
            self.progress = 0.0
            self.repaint()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)

        # Create the background widget
        self.background_widget = BackgroundWidget()

        # Set the background widget as the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.background_widget)

        # Create the clock label
        self.clock_label = QLabel(self.background_widget)
        self.clock_label.setStyleSheet("color: white; font-size: 48px;")

        # Create a layout for the background widget and add the clock label to it
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.background_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.clock_label)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Update the clock every second
        self.update_clock()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_clock)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def update_clock(self):
        current_time = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        current_time_str = current_time.toString("hh:mm:ss")
        self.clock_label.setText(current_time_str)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Set the dark mode theme
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    palette = app.palette()
    palette.setColor(palette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(palette.WindowText, QColor(250, 250, 250))
    app.setPalette(palette)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your computation for the progress is quite odd: instead of updating the current progress, you're applying a "recursive" formula that considers the *previous* progress but not the *new* target. This doesn't help solving the issue, and also gives an inconsistent visual result: the seconds bar almost never coincides with the actual position of seconds in the clock face. Also, the target is wrong because when a new minute begins, the value of `second` is 0, while it should be 60 in order to properly get the proportion of the circle.